# Open a buffer from within vim and jump to a specific line in one command

Tags: vim

When opening a file with vim from the terminal, I'm able to jump directly to line `123` with `vim myFile.txt +123`.

How can I do the same from within vim when opening a new buffer with, for instance, `:e myFile.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do `:e +123 myFile.txt`. See `:help :e` and `:help +cmd` for details.